# Custom kwarg in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

Today I have 2 URLs

```
router.register(r'question_type', QuestionTypeViewSet)
router.register(r'question', QuestionViewSet)
```

But I need something like this

```
router.register(r'question_type', QuestionTypeViewSet)
router.register(r'question_type/question_type_pk/question', QuestionViewSet)
```

My viewsets

```
class QuestionTypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   serializer_class = QuestionTypeSerializer
   queryset = QuestionType.objects.all()
```

What I wanna to do with QuestionViewSet

```
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   serializer_class = QuestionSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):

       queryset = Question.objects.filter(
           question_type__id=self.kwargs['question_type_id'])

       return queryset
```

How should I make the question url?

Comment: This package may help? https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers

Comment: This work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by this [session](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions) of the documentation, you can achieve this by adding extra action to the `QuestionViewSet` viewset.

From the documentation here is how this `r'question_type/{pk}/question'` can be achieved

`from rest_framework.decorators import action`

.........

```
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ your current code """
    
    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def question(self, request, pk=True):
        serializer = YourQuestionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(): 
            """ your logic here """
```